# propagating access token between microservices

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on microservices application where the client application sends the `access token` to `orders` microservice with the `POST` call. When saving the order, the inventory micro-service should be called to update the inventory. The Inventory microservice `updateIntentory` method should also be protected.

In this use case, should I be propagate the same `access token` to the `inventory` microservice and restrict the api access to update inventory or should I make use of `client-credentials` grant flow to allow `saveOrder` method in the `order` microservice to invoke the `updateInventory` method in the `inventory microservice`.

Note: Both the `order` and `inventory` microservices are acting as resource servers.
What is the right approach.

Comment: I think what you're describing is that the `orders` and `inventory` services are acting as a [resource server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/servlet/oauth2/oauth2-resourceserver.html). If the `orders` service calls `inventory`, you can implement the token-relay pattern or use `client_credentials` with a separate `client_id`, depending on whether the two services share the same authorization scheme or not.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Both the order and inventory microservices are acting as resource servers. How to implement the `token-relay` pattern? Also, what is the `authorization scheme`

Comment: Please google before asking new questions in comments.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I did not find any practical guide and hence asked in the comment.

Comment: By "authorization scheme" I simply mean your application's requirements for authorization. For example, if both services require `ROLE_USER` to execute the desired operation, vs. one requiring a completely different level of access from the other; another example would be whether you determine what the user has access to in the same way between the two services, vs. very different ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question:

**BOUNDARIES**

If you were calling an external API belonging to someone else you would definitely use client credentials to get a token that entitles you to call that API.

**MICROSERVICES**

If the data owner is the same then most commonly you can simply forward the access token. This is how OAuth is meant to work: a scalable architecture that only requires simple code:

- Client gets an access token with scopes for multiple APIs
- Each API validates the JWT
- Each API verifies its own scopes
- Each API trusts the claims in the JWT and uses them for authorization

The [Scope Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/) article explains this for a real world system.

**TRUST BOUNDARIES AND HIGHER PRIVILEGES**

It is common to get a fresh token for high security operations, such as redirecting the user with a payment scope, or using [token exchange](https://oauth.net/2/token-exchange/) before calling a less trusted API. This should be the exception rather than the rule though.

Comment: How to propagate the token from one microservice to another? Is there a standard way since `OAuth2RestTemplate` is deprecated in Spring Boot.

Comment: Just by a simple HTTP request - eg use the Apache HTTP client. All you have to do is send the bearer token in the HTTP Authorization header - avoid Spring Security for simple API calls. See [this guide](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/library/jaxrs-client-httpclient-get-post/)